# MacOS - every 15 minutes or so, network gets restarted

Tags: wifi

macOS Catalina 10.15.6

I'm connected over WiFi (no Ethernet at my home). Recently, I started having an issue where my laptop resets its Wifi connection every 15 minutes or so. This is how it looks like during ping:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51839 ttl=114 time=21.525 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51840 ttl=114 time=25.298 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51841 ttl=114 time=19.312 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51842 ttl=114 time=33.103 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51843 ttl=114 time=21.277 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51844 ttl=114 time=33.867 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51845 ttl=114 time=199.673 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51846 ttl=114 time=82.329 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51847 ttl=114 time=118.550 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 51848
Request timeout for icmp_seq 51849
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51850 ttl=114 time=62.326 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51851 ttl=114 time=44.070 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51852 ttl=114 time=147.704 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51853 ttl=114 time=33.907 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51854 ttl=114 time=20.447 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51855 ttl=114 time=23.452 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51856 ttl=114 time=22.655 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51857 ttl=114 time=58.602 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51858 ttl=114 time=22.962 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51859 ttl=114 time=25.111 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51860 ttl=114 time=24.925 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51861 ttl=114 time=183.161 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51862 ttl=114 time=138.105 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51863 ttl=114 time=23.958 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51864 ttl=114 time=25.888 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51865 ttl=114 time=21.209 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51866 ttl=114 time=25.707 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51867 ttl=114 time=23.296 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=51868 ttl=114 time=24.446 ms
```

I opened Console and these are the logs from two instances:

Instance 1:

```
default 08:03:41.054373-0700    syspolicyd  Error checking with notarization daemon: 3
default 08:03:41.065244-0700    syspolicyd  MacOS error: -67062
default 08:03:41.068233-0700    syspolicyd  MacOS error: -67062
default 08:03:42.409636-0700    WindowServer    Sender lacks privileges to install non-process event taps
default 08:03:42.410420-0700    WindowServer    Sender lacks privileges to install non-process event taps
default 08:03:45.288172-0700    trustd  Task <A770BEDC-016B-4FE8-8BA1-E04A24845E7B>.<1> resuming, QOS(0x15) Voucher <private>
default 08:03:45.290020-0700    trustd  Connection 3063: starting, TC(0x0)
default 08:03:45.290220-0700    trustd  [C3063 6425FB1D-199E-4C39-B72D-999E43F594FE Hostname#a669a86b:80 tcp, pid: 83782, url hash: 5881fca6] start
default 08:03:45.291062-0700    trustd  nw_connection_report_state_with_handler_on_nw_queue [C3063] reporting state preparing
default 08:03:45.293889-0700    trustd  Task <A770BEDC-016B-4FE8-8BA1-E04A24845E7B>.<1> setting up Connection 3063
default 08:03:45.344582-0700    sentineld   Task <DFF51037-8446-4699-8F6F-6B7BA80864DF>.<20665> resuming, QOS(0x15) Voucher (null)
default 08:03:45.345335-0700    sentineld   Task <DFF51037-8446-4699-8F6F-6B7BA80864DF>.<20665> {strength 1, tls 8, ct 0, sub 0, sig 0, ciphers 1, bundle 0, builtin 0}
default 08:03:45.345721-0700    sentineld   Task <DFF51037-8446-4699-8F6F-6B7BA80864DF>.<20665> now using Connection 461
default 08:03:45.346019-0700    sentineld   Task <DFF51037-8446-4699-8F6F-6B7BA80864DF>.<20665> sent request, body S 160
default 08:03:47.311208-0700    locationd   WifiService, event, com.apple.coreWLAN.notification.scanCache, ignore since LS off
error   08:03:47.385354-0700    SystemUIServer  NetworkExtra: failed to get user preferences from current connection: No such key
default 08:03:47.381016-0700    loginwindow -[MCXDLauncher(Private) startNetworkChangeThreadTimer:] |      Starting timer
```

Instance 2:

```
default 08:18:45.376408-0700    sentineld   Task <3AA3FB33-B286-49BB-A30A-CBF2768285DE>.<20696> resuming, QOS(0x15) Voucher (null)
default 08:18:45.377022-0700    sentineld   Task <3AA3FB33-B286-49BB-A30A-CBF2768285DE>.<20696> {strength 1, tls 8, ct 0, sub 0, sig 0, ciphers 1, bundle 0, builtin 0}
default 08:18:45.377283-0700    sentineld   Task <3AA3FB33-B286-49BB-A30A-CBF2768285DE>.<20696> now using Connection 461
default 08:18:45.377577-0700    sentineld   Task <3AA3FB33-B286-49BB-A30A-CBF2768285DE>.<20696> sent request, body S 160
default 08:18:46.411617-0700    taskgated   MacOS error: -67062
default 08:18:46.453077-0700    sentineld_helper    MacOS error: -67062
default 08:18:46.457108-0700    sentineld_helper    MacOS error: -67062
default 08:18:46.461081-0700    sentineld_helper    MacOS error: -67062
default 08:18:46.463893-0700    sentineld_helper    MacOS error: -67062
default 08:18:47.438922-0700    WindowServer    Sender lacks privileges to install non-process event taps
default 08:18:47.439769-0700    WindowServer    Sender lacks privileges to install non-process event taps
default 08:18:47.487621-0700    loginwindow -[MCXDLauncher(Private) startNetworkChangeThreadTimer:] |      Starting timer
error   08:18:47.490614-0700    SystemUIServer  NetworkExtra: failed to get user preferences from current connection: No such key
```

Before I reach out to SentinelOne (who provide an endpoint security product), I wanted to understand if this had anything to do with them. The Console logs are full of Sentinel-related lines all the time, so I have no indication it is their software that's causing this.

The startNetworkChangeThreadTimer is suspicious to me. A Google search turned up nothing for it.

Comment: Where do you see your network restarts?

Comment: I lose network connectivity for a few seconds.

Comment: Not what I asked.  Where in all of that diagnostic info do you see a drop every 15 mins?

Comment: You see the ping snippet that has drops in it? I have ping running 24/7 and I see these every 15-20 minutes (around 1000 "icmp_seq" steps). I only notice these on Zoom calls because the video/audio glitches.

Comment: That's not indicative of a network disconnect.  You are pinging from your computer, to your WAP, through your firewall, across 7 to 10 hops to get to Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8) . How do you know where the packet drops?  It could be dropping between your local ISP and the backbone, or the backbone and Google.  If you want to analyze your network, you have to stay local and to see a disconnect -  you have to see where the *connection* drops, not where a packet or two is lost because (especially) with WiFi, interfering radio signals can cause packets loss.

Comment: Valid point. How would you keep "ping" the wifi? Would you use ping with the local router's IP, or something else?

Comment: I wouldn't use ping.  You have to look through your console log for when your network went down.  As a test, open console, cycle the WiFi on/off then watch for the entries.  That's what you have to look for in the logs.  A better test would be to use ethernet so you can unplug and plug back in as it will better simulate a "drop."  You shouldn't use ping because it's primary function is to test for latency.

Comment: You also have to identify the problem you're trying to solve.  A couple dropped packets will be unnoticed during normal activities like browsing, email and file transfer.

Comment: Update: first of all - I'm trying to solve Zoom problems. When these packet drops happen, I miss 4 seconds of discussion on zoom (sometimes, material). Also, I've started pinging the local router instead of 8.8.8.8, and the packet drops are happening at the local level - so not related to ISP. 

I'm using the Google Wifi, so nothing I can really troubleshoot with it. That's why I'm trying to troubleshoot on the laptop's side.

Comment: Ok..what you need to understand is about 95% of the connection you have no control over.  Your "domain" so to speak is from your device to the LAN side of your cable modem.  After that, you're at the mercy of the numerous ISPs, backbone providers, and hosting companies providing the service.  This is why `ping` across the Internet is about the worst thing you can use - you have no idea where the problem lies.  If you were pinging your router that would be a different story.  But...  it's WiFi.  Packets ***WILL*** get dropped.  There's no perfect WiFi network.

Comment: @Allan, I believe you misunderstood my last comment. I'm seeing the packet drops when pinging my local router as well, not just 8.8.8.8. That means the issue is either on my Mac, or in the local Wifi.